# how to code for multiple modals where some of them are carousels with different number of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with several buttons, when each button is clicked a different modal pops up. Some of the modals are carousels, the code I have works but for only one of the carousels, when I have more than one I get extra empty slides on all the carousels. So I'm guessing my code is counting all the slides from all the carousels together. Im trying to have write something where it says if this modal is clicked then get the slides from the clicked modal only but Im struggling with that.

These are the bits of relevant code:

```js
<script>
//Carousel
 
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n); 
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     /*dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");*/
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  /*dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";*/
}

  </script>

 
<script>
//Display corresponding modal of letter that is clicked 
 
$(".button").on("click", function() {
   var modal = $(this).data("modal");
   $(modal).show();
   document.body.classList.add("modal-open");  
 
});
  

  
//Close modal when "x" is clicked or when area outside modal is clicked
$(".modal").on("click", function(e) {
   var className = e.target.className;
   if(className === "modal" || className === "close"){
   $(this).closest(".modal").hide();
   document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
  }
});
  

  
  
</script>
```

```html
<button class="button" data-modal="#modalOne"><img id="myImg" src=""></button>
<button class="button" data-modal="#modalB"><img id="myImg" src=""></button>
<button class="button" data-modal="#modalC"><img id="myImg" src=""></button>
 
<!-- The Modal -->
 <div id="modalA" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <span class="close">×</span>
 
 <div class= "mySlides">
   <img class="gif" src="" width="100" height="100"  >
   
   <h4>Title</h4>
      <p> content </p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="mySlides">
   <h4 Title</h4>
   <p> content </p>
   
 </div>
  
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal B -->
 <div id="modalB" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <span class="close">×</span>
 
 <div class="mySlides">
   <img class="gif" src="" width="100" height="100"  >
   <h4></h4>
      <p></p>
 </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<!-- The Modal C -->
 <div id="modalC" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <span class="close">×</span>
 <div class="mySlides">
   <img class="gif" src="" width="100" height="100"  >
   
   <h4></h4>
      <p></p>
  
 
 <div class="mySlides">
  
   <h4></h4>
   <p></p>
 </div>
 <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this line

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

You count all the elements with class name of "mySlides", which is ALL of the slides in the HTML document.

Add code in your button click routine to count the number of slides in the corresponding modal:

Add this at the top of the javascript:

```
var modal = "modalA";
showDivs(slideIndex, modal);
```

Change the button click to:

```
$(".button").on("click", function() {
   modal = $(this).data("modal").text();
   $("#" + modal).show();
   document.body.classList.add("modal-open");  
});
```

Modify your showDivs function to include the new variable:

```
  function showDivs(n, modal) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementById(modal).getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
       }
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     /*dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");*/
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  /*dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";*/
}
```

Finally, change the data-modal attributes of your buttons to read:

```
<button class="button" data-modal="modalA">
<button class="button" data-modal="modalB">
<button class="button" data-modal="modalC">
```

You will also need to update the lines:

```
function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n, modal); 
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n, modal);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like it should work but I keep trying it and the carousel didn't work unless I changed the  slideCount = document.getElementById(modal).getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); to  slideCount = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); but then that left me with the same issue as before

Comment: Just realised I left off .length to do the actual count of the slides! Updated solution.

Comment: It still doesn't work with the .length and the end. The carousel only works if I add .length in the showDivs function after every slideCount. But still counts the "myslides" of the every element on the page because I had to remove the "getElementById(modal)." (I also tried slideCount = document.getElementsByClassName(modal).getElementsByClassName("mySlides").length; and that didnt work either

Comment: Can you put an alert (or breakpoint) after the line which counts the slides in the button click function to show the value of slideCount? Is it counting correctly?

Comment: It counts the number of slides when the line is slideCount = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); be it it counts all the slides in the page but if I have slideCount = document.getElementById(modal).getElementsByClassName("mySlides").length; OR slideCount = document.getElementsByClassName("modal").getElementsByClassName("mySlides").length; it doesn't count them at all.

Comment: I've been debugging and I've seen where I was going wrong! My original idea of passing the visible modal to the function as a string works so much better.  If you don't want to display a modal at all at first change the original var modal="ModalA" to var modal="" and test for this in the showDivs function.

Comment: hmm..now the modal will not open when I click the button

Comment: Have you got the "#" + in the $("#" + modal).show() part ofteh button click function?

Comment: Also need to change ModalOne to ModalA

Comment: Yeah I have changed both of those things, and the modals no longer open...so weird everything looks fine

Comment: try forcing the modal to text (also I've removed the extra var - not needed)

Answer (score 0):

You can also choose to use PipesJS + Modala

```
<carousel delay="5000" file-order="pic1.png;pic2.gif;pic3.jpg" boxes="4" interval="1" id="carousel-here" insert="carousel-here"></carousel>
```

Yes that will create a carousel of the 3 pictures, with the first repeating on the end and every "delay='n'" ms it will move automatically. If you don't want it to move automatically that will be done very soon.

Pick it up here:

[PipesJS + Modala](https://github.com/wise-penny/pipes)

You can see it working at [g0d.me - pipes](http://g0d.me/pipes)